# How to Prevent Concurrent Querying While Series of Transactions is Being Executed in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, concurrency, locking

I have been trying to solve an issue, which is to prevent another query from being served until a series of transaction have been completed.

I am thinking that when a user fires two or more simultaneous request to Node server, it might cause some issues when read/write to MongoDB, thus posing a security issue. The pseudocode looks like this:

```
//When user buy something, check if the user has sufficient balance, then send a deliver order and deduct the balance.
app.post('/buy', (req, res) => {
    //Step 1: Get balance from MongoDB with mongoose
    balance.find(...)

    // Step 2: Check if balance sufficient, issue a delivery order
    if (balance >= price){ //run delivery order code to deliver item }

    // Step 3: Deduct balance, then write new balance back to Mongo database
    balance = balance - price;
    balance.findOneAndUpdate(...)
})
```

Here lies a problem. If the user simultaneously fire two or more requests, each might have a chance to read the database. Because of this, they pass the balance check, and their actions will be succesfully completed with the delivery orders. If the user only have enough balance to buy one item, it will cause a 'double spending' problem because the user will have successfully bought more than once.

My question for this situation is: How to prevent the next query (which will be within millisecond after the previous query) from being run at Step 1, until all the transactions have been completed for the previous query (until Step 3 is finished)?

MongoDB documentation mentioned something like concurrency and locking, however it is not stated how to use them in a series of transaction, as above. It is also not clear if the so called 'multi-document transaction' is applicable in this situation, also lacking the code to show how to use them. Stack Overflow has only a few related questions, but the solutions are a bit vague, and almost all don't have a solution code as a reference.

Comment: try synchronizing the request using npm-sync

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does [implement transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) as of 4.0, so you should use them if you are looking for transactional behavior across multiple operations.

The linked page also provides examples in various languages.

Comment: Yes, however does it mean other query won't be able to access the collections while the transactions are in progress? This is because of the issue mentioned above in the question. The documentation doesn't seem to address it.

Comment: Your question uses the phrase "until all the transactions have been completed" but your code does not have any transactions. If your question is specifically about transactions, revise your code to use transactions. Otherwise revise your wording to use neutral terms like "operation". As it is I am not clear what exactly you are asking.